# clearTimeout doesn't work due to ajax jquery function, bootstrap modal event not handled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, settimeout

I’ve a ridiculous problem with my javascript **setTimeout** and **jquery ajax** function.

I’ve a webpage who needed to be refreshed every x seconds.

I use a setTimeout who call my ajax function every x seconds.

The user has the opportunity to use a boostrap modal to enter information.
What I want is to clear the timeout when the modal is shown and restart the timeout when the user closed.

**My problem is on the event  “shown.bs.modal”  none of the functions are executed, even the alerts so my setTimout is still running while the modal is open.**

If the DOM is uploaded  while the modal is shown, the modal source code will be deleted and so I’ll have a frozen webpage, without scrollbar.

**The problem comes from the ajax function**.
If I change the code of doRefresh to just an alert(); everything works perfectly.

```
//refresh delay in ms
var delayRefresh=5000;

// stored setTimeout's id
var refresh;

//First call of the ajax function
$(document).ready(function(){
    refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){doRefresh();}, delayRefresh);
});

//code executed when the user open a modal
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {          
     alert(refresh);
    //Stopped the refresh
    clearTimeout(refresh);  
});

//code executed when the user close the modal
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
    alert(refresh);
    //restart of the refresh
    refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){doRefresh();}, delayRefresh);  
    alert(refresh);
});


/* Fonction that run the ajax request to the server */  
var doRefresh = function (){        
    $.ajax({
        type:"PUT",
        url:"<c:url value="/checklist"/>",
        contentType: false,
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
                // DOM update
                $("#content_needed_to_be_updated").html(data) ;
                //restart of the refresh
                refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){doRefresh();},delayRefresh);
                                
            },
            error:function(xhr){                    
                toastr.error('Le serveur n\'a pas pu être atteint.', 'Erreur !');        
                //restart of the refresh
                refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){doRefresh();}, delayRefresh+20000);
            }
        });             
};
```

New version:

```
//refresh delay in ms
var delayRefresh=30000;

// stored setTimeout's id
var idSetTimeout;

var refesh=function(){
    idSetTimeout=window.setTimeout(function(){doRefresh();}, delayRefresh);
}; 

//First call of the ajax function
$(document).ready(function(){
    refesh();
});

//code executed when the user open a modal
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {          
     alert(idSetTimeout);
    //Stopped the refresh
    clearTimeout(idSetTimeout); 
});

//code executed when the user close the modal
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
    alert(idSetTimeout);
    //restart of the refresh
    refresh();  
    alert(idSetTimeout);
});


/* Fonction that run the ajax request to the server */  
var doRefresh = function (){        
    $.ajax({
        type:"PUT",
        url:"<c:url value="/checklist"/>",
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
                // DOM update
                $("#content_needed_to_be_updated").html(data) ;
                //restart of the refresh
                refresh();                                      
            },
            error:function(xhr){                    
                toastr.error('Le serveur n\'a pas pu être atteint.', 'Erreur !');        
                //restart of the refresh
                refresh();  
            }
        });             
};
```

Comment: Asynchronous call...If the call is made before the the Ajax call returns, it will call the callback and start the timer. It has no clue you do not want to start it. Add logic and why have the same setTimeout calls everywhere, make it a common method!

Comment: Thanks for your help, even if i increase the delay to 30 seconds and i set the async to false for the ajax method, it still doesn't work. My alert is not displayed when i open a modal.

Comment: While the first call of doRefresh hasn't been done, my actions linked to the modal events work. But after the first call of doRefresh, it doesn't work anymore. you're right, it's due to the Asynchronous call but now i've setted it to false and i still have the same problem ...

Comment: Maybe you could left your timeout set, and on doRefresh ask if the modal is shown before making the ajax call

Comment: I did fixed my problem a long time ago. The problem was when the DOM was updated by the ajax function, the HTML returned has the source code of the modal. Then i had to reinitialise the event handler with the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave your timeout set, and simply check whether the modal is shown or not before making the ajax call to the server.

```
var doRefresh = function () {
    if (!$(".modal").data('bs.modal').isShown)
    {
        $.ajax({
            // your code...
        });
    }
}
```